# Force universal app to run iPhone version on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, configuration, ios-universal-app

I've had an iPhone product on iTunes for a while and have superseded it with a universal app which has been met with approval except from one customer who wants to run the iPhone version on his iPad as he preferred the larger inputs and working of the iPhone.

Is there any way to configure the app to run either as native iPad app or iPhone app on iPad at runtime?  Seems an odd request but customer is quite insistant.

Thanks

/Fitto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that, except making separates versions for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Thanks. I thought not. Just needed confirmation. Bit of a blow really, but hey!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could have some setting that would load the iPhone storyboard on the iPad, but it would still display full screen, and not in compatibility mode, which is probably the way this particular user wants it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running some sort of source control, you could change the project to be "iPhone Only" and then test on the iPad, then later revert the changes made to make it a Universal app again